# How to delete one cron job via SSH?

Tags: php, ssh, cron

I am programming a script that needs to add crons dynamically in PHP. I use this command to insert a new job:

```
ssh2_exec($connection, '(echo "* * * * * /usr/local/bin/php -q /home/username/www/index.php 1 '.$user.' >/dev/null 2>&1 ") | crontab -u username -');
```

Where `$user` is a variable.

Now, if the `$user` is deleted I want to remove their related cron job.

Is there any way to delete specific line from crontab? I know that

```
crontab -u username -r
```

will delete all crons of the username, but I don't want that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the solution after a period of time and a much of tests

```
 ssh2_exec($connection, 'crontab -u username -l > /home/crontmp/tmp.txt;replace -s "0 0 1 1 * /usr/local/bin/php -q /home/username/www/index.php 1 '.$userPhone.' >/dev/null 2>&1" "" -- /home/crontmp/tmp.txt;crontab -u username -r;(cat /home/crontmp/tmp.txt) | crontab -u username -');
```

the idea is , get all crons for the user then add it to a tmp file then replace the remove the line that i want to delete then add the modified file to cron file again

Answer (score 0):

Can't help you very much with libssh2 but you can accomplish this with [phpseclib, a pure PHP SSH implementation](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/) easily enough.

```
<?php
include('Net/SSH2.php');

$ssh = new Net_SSH2('www.domain.tld');
if (!$ssh->login('username', 'password')) {
    exit('Login Failed');
}

$ssh->read('username@username:~$');
$ssh->write("crontab -e\n"); // note the "\n"
$ssh->sleep(1); // you could probably $ssh->read() up to a certain byte but idk what that byte would be
$ssh->write("/username\n");
$ssh->sleep(1); // $ssh->read() again
$ssh->write("dd");
$ssh->sleep(1);
$ssh->write(":exit\n";
?>
```

Comment: sorry but , if write a comment for every line from $ssh->read('username@username:~$'); , i can't understant the lines

Comment: That's no doubt because of ANSI escape codes: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code To "decode" them you'd need a terminal emulator. See http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/ssh/examples.html#top

Comment: we can ignore the php coding , i want a code of ssh command to delete one jop from cron